# Efficient Spark left join on multiple columns when dataframes are partitioned by a single column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, left-join, database-partitioning

I have two large dataframes `df1` and `df2` partitioned by column `a`, and I want to efficiently compute a left join on both `a` and another column `b`:

`df1.join(df2, on=['a', 'b'], how='left_outer')`

When written as above, Spark reshuffles both dataframes by key `(a, b)`, which is extremely inefficient. Instead, I would like it to take advantage of the existing partitioning by `a` to avoid the shuffle (performing the join within each partition), which should be a lot faster (especially since I have further processing steps that benefit from this partitioning).

**Is there any way to prevent this shuffle and obtain a resulting dataframe partitioned by `a` ?**

Note that if it was an inner join I could do the following, but (1) I'm not sure if it'd be efficient, and anyway (2) it doesn't work with a left join (I'm only providing it in case it'd help someone else):

`df1.join(df2, on=['a'], how='inner').filter(df1.b == df2.b)`

PS: both dataframes are too large to be broadcasted

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: @vikrantrana sadly no, I ended up doing it manually with the RDD API...

Comment: would you like to share us the code using rdd API or may be as an answer.. Thanks in advance

Comment: @vikrantrana Well my code is very specific to my use case, as it is part of a long processing chain. This was almost one year ago too and I don't remember all details, but at high level I used the RDD API to join on 'a' and then processed each partition in pure Python to do the join on 'b' (I think with Pandas) -- partitions were small enough in my use case.

Comment: I also had some issue with joining and it did it via breaking the dataframe into chunks and repartition it and then process each partition serially in a loop. see link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524062/efficient-pyspark-join/53720497#53720497